# Algorithm to balance candies among students

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems

Let's say N students

```
S1, S2, ... SN
```

with their respective candies count

```
c1, c2,... cN
```

The ask is to distribute the candies (whole number only) as evenly as possible among the students, with last student can get the extra candy.

Hence, average cookie `(c1 + c2 + ... + cn)/N`

E.g
student -> number of cookies

```
S1 -> 3
S2 -> 4
S3 -> 6
```

The expected outcome should be the below (as evenly distributed as possible)

```
S1 -> 4
S2 -> 4
S3 -> 5
```

Does any simple algorithm exists for this kind of problem?